# Update a column

Tags: sql, sql-update

i want to add gender in Peshwar table. 
i want to add gender all fields of Peshwar table where gender is empty,
returned by this query

```
select  
    Gender_lookup_Table.
    Gender
from 
    Gender_lookup_Table,Peshwar
where 
    Gender_lookup_Table.initial_name like substring 
        (Peshwar.Student_Name, 1,CHARINDEX(' ',Peshwar.Student_Name,0))
```

using this to fill gender column :S but i doesnot work.

```
update Peshwar
set 
gender=
    (
        select  
            Gender_lookup_Table.Gender
        from 
            Gender_lookup_Table,Peshwar
        where 
            Gender_lookup_Table.initial_name like substring
                 (Peshwar.Student_Name, 1,CHARINDEX(' ',Peshwar.Student_Name,0))
)
where gender= NULL
```

i need a for loop to fill all column?? :s

Answer (score 2):

first, when comparing with `NULL` values, it should be `IS NULL` not `= NULL`.

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.gender = b.gender
FROM    peshwar a
        INNER JOIN gender_lookup_Table b
            ON b.initial_name LIKE SUBSTRING(a.Student_Name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', a.Student_Name, 0))
```

- [UPDATE with JOIN](http://blog.ookamikun.com/2008/03/mysql-update-with-join.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
update p
SET p.gender = g.gender
FROM peshwar p
INNER JOIN Gender_lookup_Table g 
        ON g.initial_name LIKE SUBSTRING(p.Student_Name, 
                                         1,  
                                         CHARINDEX(' ', p.Student_Name,0))
WHERE p.gender IS NULL
```

Comment: +1 only you have identified the mess and cleared it nicely. Need a closing bracket for the `SUBSTRING` function

Comment: @ShanzaButt `SUBSTRING` function needs a closing `)`

Comment: @ShanzaButt It was a missing `)` before the `WHERE` clause as Kaf pointed out. See my edit.